# NSURLSessionUploadTask hangs during upload on iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsurlsession

I'm experiencing a very weird problem.
I'm doing background uploading but for some reason the upload hangs and the weird part is that it happens only when using an iPhone 5c with iOS 7.1.3.
The upload hangs for several seconds (usually a bit more than 1 minute) after logging 4-5 times "keeps uploading". 
Then it starts logging again and after some seconds stops again.

I tried running the app on several devices with iOS 8.x and it worked smoothly (including an iPhone 4s, so I don't think computing power could be the problem).
I tried uploading different files on different connections but the problem persists.
I even tried with the iOS 7.1 simulator and the upload went trough without a problem.
Is there some weird iOS 7.1 behavior that I'm not aware of? Am I doing something wrong?

Here's my code

```
- (void) startUploadVideo:(Video*)video {
if (video.videoPath == nil) {
    video.videoPath = ExportPathFromMedia(video);
}

video.amazonBucketKey = AmazonBucketKey(video.assetID);

NSString *contentType = @"video/mp4";

NSURL *preSignedURL = [self obtainPreSignedURLRequestForPUTDataDaskWithKey:video.amazonBucketKey contentType:contentType];

NSMutableURLRequest *newRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:preSignedURL];
newRequest.cachePolicy =NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData;
[newRequest setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
[newRequest setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSURLSession *session = [UploadManager sharedInstance].session;

NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:newRequest fromFile:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://%@",video.videoPath]]];

[uploadTask resume];
}


- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didSendBodyData:(int64_t)bytesSent totalBytesSent:(int64_t)totalBytesSent totalBytesExpectedToSend:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToSend {
     NSLog(@"keeps uploading");
}
```

Thank you

Comment: I'd suggest watching the request in something like [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com). There's nothing special about 7.1 re uploading that I know of. Is this session a background session or foreground session? Any authentication or redirects taking place? (You might want to implement the redirect and authentication delegates and see what you see there.) BTW, when building file URL, just use `NSURL` method `fileURLWithPath` rather than building the URL manually yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I'm going to try using fileUrlWithPath and implementing the two delegates you seuggested.
The problem is arising while doing foreground upload, so I didn't even bother trying the background one.
The uploading is taking place on an Amazon S3 server so I'm using their SDK for building a presigned url.
Could it be a device related problem ? I don't really think it should make a difference but the testing device was bloated with tens of apps and all of them have active notifications.

Comment: I think it exceedingly unlikely to be a device issue (esp if it works on both iOS 8 devices and iOS 7 simulator).

Comment: My `NSURLSessionUploadTask` also stucks with Amzon servers.

Comment: @halfblood17 is that issue is resolved, even I am facing similar issue

Comment: @Raghav unfortunately no.. due to time constraints we just decided to drop the support for versions below iOS 8. Sorry